# Using awscala with STS

Tags: java, scala, amazon-s3

I have a very simple scala project where I am trying to copy files to and from s3 as part of a perf test.  My code runs in kubernetes and my organization is using STS.  I have a working service account that is applied to my container with helm.  From the command line I can successfully copy files using "aws s3 cp" but I can't get it to work with awscala.

Here is my code:

```
package util

import java.io.{File}
import java.nio.file.{Files, Path, StandardCopyOption}
import awscala._, s3._, sts._

import scala.util.Properties

trait AWSStorageClient {

  val bucketName: String = "bucketName"
  val fileNameSuffix: String = java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName()
  val downloadPath: String = "src/gatling/resources"

  implicit val s3 = S3.at(Region.US_WEST_2)
}

trait fsUtils {

  def getListOfDirs(dir: String): List[File] = {
    val d = new File(dir)
    if (d.exists && d.isDirectory) {
      d.listFiles.filter(_.isDirectory).toList
    } else {
      List[File]()
    }
  }

}

object LogUploader extends AWSStorageClient with fsUtils {

  @throws[Exception]
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val fileList = getListOfDirs("build/reports/gatling")
    val reportDir = fileList.head
    println("fileList: " + fileList)

    val bucket = s3.bucket(bucketName).get

    bucket.put(s"simulation-$fileNameSuffix.log",
      new java.io.File((s"$reportDir/simulation.log"))
    )
  }
}

object DataFileDownloader extends AWSStorageClient with fsUtils {

  @throws[Exception]
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val bucket = s3.bucket(bucketName).get

    bucket.get("7500.csv")

    val d1 = new File("/7500.csv").toPath
    val d2 = new File("/src/gatling/resources/7500.csv").toPath

    Files.move(d1, d2, StandardCopyOption.ATOMIC_MOVE)

  }

}
```

This is the error:

```
 Exception in thread "main" com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied
```

DataFileDownloader & LogUploader are supposed to be run from gradle before and after a gatling simulation respectively.

Does anyone have any ideas regarding how to get my code to work with STS?  Do I need to assume role somehow or provide my service account arn in my code someplace?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Additional Note:
Based on this: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2/issues/1470

I think I may need to do something like this:

```
import software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.WebIdentityTokenFileCredentialsProvider;
...
S3Client s3 = S3Client.builder()
                              .credentialsProvider(WebIdentityTokenFileCredentialsProvider.create())
                              .region(region)
                              .build();
```

But I am not sure.  I am new to Scala and Awscala.

Comment: It's not clear what error you are getting or what problem you are experiencing. You could check that your credentials are properly configured in one of the places described in the docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v2/developer-guide/credentials.html (env, jvm props, file) or provide them explicitly to the client to test. Try to run this from your machine where you have cmd working vs kubernetes. Print your client config to see what's in there (connection details, etc).

Comment: Thanks, @yǝsʞǝla.  I added the error.  I looked at your link, too, and am still trying to figure out what should work.  I see these env vars in my container: AWS_ROLE_ARN=arn:aws:iam::999999999:role/roleName
AWS_WEB_IDENTITY_TOKEN_FILE=/var/run/secrets/eks.amazonaws.com/serviceaccount/token

Comment: I finally fell back on just using the java aws libraries:  aws-java-sdk-s3 & aws-java-sdk-sts.  I think that awscala is using out if date versions of these or other aws java libs

Answer (score 0):

The java code snippet you have is correct, you must assume the Service Account Role. I can confirm java libraries 1.11.719 and up work correctly.

To confirm, I've also observed the same behaviour where the AWS CLI succeeds but JAVA code fails with a permissions error.

```
import software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.WebIdentityTokenFileCredentialsProvider;
...
S3Client s3 = S3Client.builder()
                              .credentialsProvider(WebIdentityTokenFileCredentialsProvider.create())
                              .region(region)
                              .build();
```